# How do I do a rolling cumsum over consecutive rows of a tibble in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I have a toy example of a tibble. 
What is the most efficient way to sum two consecutive rows of y grouped by x

```r
library(tibble)
l = list(x = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), y = c(1, 4, 3, 3, 7, 0))

df <- as_tibble(l)
df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     a     1
#> 2     b     4
#> 3     a     3
#> 4     b     3
#> 5     a     7
#> 6     b     0
```

So the output would be something like this

```r
   group   sum  seq
     a      4     1
     a     10     2
     b      7     1
     b      3     2
```

I'd like to use the tidyverse and possibly roll_sum() from the RcppRoll package
and have the code so that a variable length of consecutive rows could be used for real world data in which there would be many groups

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is use `group_by %>% do` where you can customize the returned data frame in `do`:

```
library(RcppRoll); library(tidyverse)

n = 2
df %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    do(
        data.frame(
            sum = roll_sum(.$y, n), 
            seq = seq_len(length(.$y) - n + 1)
        )
    )

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   x [2]
#      x   sum   seq
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1     a     4     1
#2     a    10     2
#3     b     7     1
#4     b     3     2
```

---

*Edit*: Since this is not as efficient, probably due to the data frame construction header and binding data frames on the go, here is an improved version (still somewhat slower than `data.table` but not as much now):

```
df %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    summarise(sum = list(roll_sum(y, n)), seq = list(seq_len(n() -n + 1))) %>%
    unnest()
```

---

*Timing*, use @Matt's data and setup:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)
library(stringi) ## Only included for ability to generate random strings

## Generate data with arbitrary number of groups and rows --------------
rowCount   <- 100000
groupCount <- 10000
sumRows    <- 2L
set.seed(1)

l <- tibble(x = sample(stri_rand_strings(groupCount,3),rowCount,rep=TRUE),
            y = sample(0:10,rowCount,rep=TRUE))

## Using dplyr and tibble -----------------------------------------------

ptm <- proc.time() ## Start the clock

dplyr_result <- l %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    summarise(sum = list(roll_sum(y, n)), seq = list(seq_len(n() -n + 1))) %>%
    unnest()


dplyr_time <- proc.time() - ptm ## Stop the clock

## Using data.table instead ----------------------------------------------

library(data.table)

ptm <- proc.time() ## Start the clock

setDT(l) ## Convert l to a data.table
dt_result <- l[,.(sum = RcppRoll::roll_sum(y, n = sumRows, fill = NA, align = "left"),
                  seq = seq_len(.N)),
               keyby = .(x)][!is.na(sum)]

data.table_time <- proc.time() - ptm
```

Result is:

```
dplyr_time
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.688   0.003   0.689 
data.table_time
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.422   0.009   0.430
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one approach for you. Since you want to sum up two consecutive rows, you could use `lead()` and do the calculation for `sum`. For `seq`, I think you can simply take row numbers, seeing your expected outcome. Once you are done with these operations, you arrange your data by `x` (if necessary, `x` and `seq`). Finally, you drop rows with NAs. If necessary, you may want to drop `y` by writing `select(-y)` at the end of the code.

```
group_by(df, x) %>%
mutate(sum = y + lead(y),
       seq = row_number()) %>%
arrange(x) %>%
ungroup %>%
filter(complete.cases(.))

#      x     y   sum   seq
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     a     1     4     1
#2     a     3    10     2
#3     b     4     7     1
#4     b     3     3     2
```

Answer (score 6):

I notice you asked for the *most efficient* way-- if you are looking at scaling this up to a much larger set, I would strongly recommend data.table.

```
library(data.table)
library(RcppRoll)

l[, .(sum = RcppRoll::roll_sum(y, n = 2L, fill = NA, align = "left"),
      seq = seq_len(.N)),
  keyby = .(x)][!is.na(sum)]
```

A rough benchmark comparison of this vs an answer using the tidyverse packages with 100,000 rows and 10,000 groups illustrates the significant difference.

(I used Psidom's answer instead of jazzurro's since jazzuro's did not allow for an arbritary number of rows to be summed.)

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)
library(stringi) ## Only included for ability to generate random strings

## Generate data with arbitrary number of groups and rows --------------
rowCount   <- 100000
groupCount <- 10000
sumRows    <- 2L
set.seed(1)

l <- tibble(x = sample(stri_rand_strings(groupCount,3),rowCount,rep=TRUE),
            y = sample(0:10,rowCount,rep=TRUE))

## Using dplyr and tibble -----------------------------------------------

ptm <- proc.time() ## Start the clock

dplyr_result <- l %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    do(
        data.frame(
            sum = roll_sum(.$y, sumRows), 
            seq = seq_len(length(.$y) - sumRows + 1)
        )
    )
|========================================================0% ~0 s remaining     

dplyr_time <- proc.time() - ptm ## Stop the clock

## Using data.table instead ----------------------------------------------

library(data.table)

ptm <- proc.time() ## Start the clock

setDT(l) ## Convert l to a data.table
dt_result <- l[,.(sum = RcppRoll::roll_sum(y, n = sumRows, fill = NA, align = "left"),
                  seq = seq_len(.N)),
               keyby = .(x)][!is.na(sum)]

data.table_time <- proc.time() - ptm ## Stop the clock
```

Results:

```
> dplyr_time
  user  system elapsed 
  10.28    0.04   10.36 
> data.table_time
   user  system elapsed 
   0.35    0.02    0.36 

> all.equal(dplyr_result,as.tibble(dt_result))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yes this does look like best approach. I tend to work with smaller datasets and less intensive processing but with this one it is 250,000 rows and 2,500 groups so comparable with your example. I got an even greater time disparity, I have given answer to @Psidom as i specifically mentioned tidyverse but will use yours in production

Answer (score 4):

A solution using `tidyverse` and `zoo`. This is similar to Psidom's approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  do(data_frame(x = unique(.$x), 
                sum = rollapplyr(.$y, width = 2, FUN = sum))) %>%
  mutate(seq = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x   sum   seq
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1     a     4     1
2     a    10     2
3     b     7     1
4     b     3     2
```

Comment: One typo :) `rollapply`

Comment: @Wen Thanks. `rollapplyr` also works. The default alignment is set to be "right". This is why it is called `rollapplyr`.

Comment: @Wen Thanks for the upvote. Not a silly question. I just learned the existence of `rollapplyr` from others yesterday.

Comment: Dude, that is why we love SO, learn new stuff (You) and help others (me) ~ :) cheer

Comment: Thanks  You say it improves efficiency but on some real world data your code took 35secs cf 5 for Psidom!? I think this may be due to use of the RcppRoll roll_sum() function. I took the seq out of @Psidom do call and it made v little difference but my dataset is not millions of rows

Comment: @pssguy Thanks for testing the code. I try to move operations out of the `do` call if possible, but it probably does not make sense in this case. The other reason, as you pointed out, that RcppRoll roll_sum could be faster than rollapplyr. I will remove my statement in my post shortly.

Answer (score 1):

`zoo` + `dplyr`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    mutate(sum = c(NA, rollapply(y, width = 2, sum)), 
           seq = row_number() - 1) %>% 
    drop_na()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   x [2]
      x     y   sum   seq
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     3     4     1
2     b     3     7     1
3     a     7    10     2
4     b     0     3     2
```

If the moving  window only equal to 2 using `lag`

```
df %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    mutate(sum = y + lag(y), 
    seq = row_number() - 1) %>% 
    drop_na()
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   x [2]
      x     y   sum   seq
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     3     4     1
2     b     3     7     1
3     a     7    10     2
4     b     0     3     2
```

EDIT :

```
n = 3    # your moving window 
df %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    mutate(sum = c(rep(NA, n - 1), rollapply(y, width = n, sum)), 
           seq = row_number() - n + 1) %>% 
    drop_na()
```

Comment: YesI have used lag method before but once get past 3 it's ugly

Comment: @pssguy yes,You are right.   I highlight when your moving windows is 2 , you can using `lag` or `shift`

Comment: When applying to real data with a sequence length of 17 I get error  Column `sum` must be length 32 (the group size) or one, not 17  which does not happen with other solutions. Any idea why? It seems fast otherwise

Comment: @pssguy, what is your moving windows ?

Answer (score 0):

A small variant on existing answers: first convert the data to list-column format, then use `purrr` to `map()` `roll_sum()` onto the data.

```
l = list(x = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), y = c(1, 4, 3, 3, 7, 0))
as.tibble(l) %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarize(list_y = list(y)) %>%
    mutate(rollsum = map(list_y, ~roll_sum(.x, 2))) %>%
    select(x, rollsum) %>%
    unnest %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(seq = row_number())
```

I think if you have the latest version of `purrr` you could get rid of the last two lines (the final `group_by()` and `mutate()`) by using `imap()` instead of map.